# Sending XML with AJAX POST request to ASP.NET page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have an AJAX request like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "text/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: "send.aspx",
        data:{xml:"<xml></xml>"}

    }).done(function(reply){
        console.log(reply);
    });
```

I get no errors server side or client side, but when I try and write the output to the console server side, nothing comes up. I assume this is because ASP is seeing the XML string as an actual XML object or something of the sorts?

Heres my ASP code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Request.Params["xml"]);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream);
        String xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        String xmlData = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(xml);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(xmlData);

    }
```

Take note that I used HttpUtility.UrlDecode() to decode my XML into a readable string. Thanks to [Abin Jaik](http://abinjaik.com/tag/xml-post-data-to-aspx-page/) for the code.